Ignition Installation Issues
I have a couple of packages which require ignition-math. ignition-math6 specifically - but math7 is also causing problems.
I've followed various installation guides:
https://gazebosim.org/api/math/6.0/install.html
Plus a manual build & install
In all cases I get this error:
Could not find a package configuration file provided by "ignition-math7"
  with any of the following names:

    ignition-math7Config.cmake
    ignition-math7-config.cmake

or math6 - I've tried both.
The likes of 7 should, apparently be installed on the system:
sudo apt-get install libignition-math7-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
libignition-math7-dev is already the newest version (7.4.0-3~noble).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.

Does anyone have any suggestions?
Thanks
Mark
